# Where clause in extension of a class in swift with enum and generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm new to generics and I want to apply it for this logic.

So I have created an enum of user types. I have a userModel object that contains this user type information.

Now my UIViewController A will contain a user object and a tableView. Based on the user type, the number of cells and the cell design will also change.

Basically I don't want to clutter the entire logic into cell ForRowAtIndexPath and other such methods, which is why I was looking into generics.

This is my code

```
       enum UserType : Int {
            case None = 0, Musician, Listener
        }

        class User {
            var userType : UserType = .None
        }

        class A<T:User>: UIViewController {

            var selectedUser: T?
        }


        extension A where T.userType : UserType.Musician 
         {
            func foo() { print("Musician") }
        }
```

This gives me an error

Playground execution failed:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:13:53: error: enum element 'Musician' is not a member type of 'UserType'
            extension A where T.userType : UserType.Musician {
```

I would like to know why this error is comming and if my approach is wrong.

Comment: But you’re saying in your code that T.userType should be of type UserType.Musician but it’s not a type, UserType is a type but Musician is an enum element.

Comment: so you mean that I can't check if T.userType == .Musician?

Comment: Of course you can but you can’t use it in your extension declaration like you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create `extension` you must provide only information known at *compile time*. `userType` is property of `User` and hence it's *runtime* information. It can't be used to create `extension`.

But I think you still *might* benefit from protocols and generics. I'm not sure if it suits you, but anyway here's how it can be done.

You can declare protocols for each type of user like this

```
protocol UserProtocol {
    var userType: UserType { get }

    func doYourThing()
}

protocol MusicianProtocol: UserProtocol {}
protocol ListenerProtocol: UserProtocol {}
```

and create default implementation of `UserProtocol`

```
extension UserProtocol where Self: MusicianProtocol {
    var userType: UserType { return .musician }

    func doYourThing() {
        print("Do-di-do!")
    }
}

extension UserProtocol where Self: ListenerProtocol {
    var userType: UserType { return .listener }

    func doYourThing() {
        print("Anything except vynil is garbage!")
    }
}
```

Of course this way you will need separate class for each user

```
class Musician: MusicianProtocol {}

class Listener: ListenerProtocol {}
```

but generic handling is still possible by using `UserProtocol`

```
func letsPlay(_ users: UserProtocol...) {
    for u in users {
        u.doYourThing()
    }
}


let m = Musician()
let l = Listener()

letsPlay(m, l)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this